# Map text is truncated when tiles are created in tilecache

Tags: wms, tilecache

I'm using TileCache between our corporate WMS (Cadcorp Geognosis in this case) and an openlayers map, serving Ordnance Survey data at all levels from OS MiniScale right down to MasterMap Topo.

It's all working fine with the Raster tiles, but I get down to the Topo layer (stored in a SQL Server database if that makes a difference) map text is truncated if it goes over the edge of a tile.

I know WHY this is happening, when the tile is requested from the WMS, it doesn't have the text point in its bounds, so no text is rendered. Is there a way of fixing this? Can I tell TileCache to pull off a 768x768 tile from the WMS and return the middle 256x256? Is it an issue with my WMS? Should that be handling it better?

Comment: I don't know about tilecache but GeoWebCache calls that metatiling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key term you are (probably) looking for is metatiling. This is the term that GeoServer and GeoWebCache use to describe the process of asking for a 3x3 (or 4x4) tile block and then cutting it up to make smaller tiles.

Comment: Metatiling is available in TileCache too. Many thanks.